# How to start n tasks with one GPU each?

Tags: gpu, slurm

I have a large cluster of computing nodes, each node having 6 GPUs. And I want to start, lets say, 100 workers on that thing, each one having access to exactly one single GPU.

What I do now is like this:

```
sbatch --gres=gpu:6 --gpus-per-task=1 --ntasks='100' main.sh
```

And inside the main.sh:

```
srun --gpus-per-task=1 --gres=gpu:1 -n 100 worker.sh
```

And this way, I get 100 workers started (fully using like 17 nodes). But I have a problem: the CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES is not set properly.

```
sbatch --gres=gpu:6 --gpus-per-task=1 --ntasks='100' main.sh
# CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES in main.sh: 0,1,2,3,4,5 (that's fine)
srun --gpus-per-task=1 --gres=gpu:1 -n 100 worker.sh
# CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES in worker.sh: 0,1,2,3,4,5 (this is my problem: how to assign exactly 1 GPU to each worker and to that worker alone?)
```

It might be a misunderstanding on my part on how Slurm actually works since I'm quite new programming on such HPC systems. But any clue how to achieve what I want to achieve? (each worker having exactly 1 GPU assigned to it and only it)

We use SLURM 20.02.2.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are missing here is that you should define also the number of nodes explicitly:
eg you can have
NODES=17 x 6 GPUs per NODE = 102 tasks (if you only need 100 task this means that the last node may be under utilized with only 4 tasks)

```
#SBATCH --ntasks=100
#SBATCH --gres=gpu:6
#SBATCH --nodes=17
#SBATCH --ntasks-per-node=6
#SBATCH --cpus-per-task=1   (depends on the available cores per node)

srun -l main.py
```